# Is this explanation accurate for C code that won't compile?

Tags: c

Alleged interview question and answer [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/c-will-it-compile/).

Will the following code compile (in C)?

```
#define X 8;
int main(void)
{
    ++X; // will this line compile?
}`
```

I am no expert in C, but I know some C++ and thought: of course not, you cannot increment the number 8, it is an rvalue.  Of course the preprocessor replaces the `X` with the `8` before trying to compile, and when it does try to compile, it will fail for that very reason.  Then again, I am the one reading interview question websites so then I thought who knows...

Here is the explanation given:

"Strictly speaking, the operand of the prefix (or postfix) increment operator must be a non-modifiable lvalue. Now that we know what an lvalue is, we must ask ourselves if X is an lvalue. X is a macro, which means that it does not identify a place in memory – macros use simple text replacement via the preprocessor. Because macros don’t exist in a region of memory, they are not lvalues. This means that X can not be used as an operand of the prefix increment operator. Thus, the code shown above will not compile."

Is this explanation as bunk as I think it is?

How many errors can you find above?  I think maybe that should be the interview question...

And this is just funny:

"Intuitively, you might be able to say that the code above will not compile – without knowing exactly why. However, in an interview situation, you will be expected to provide some reasoning like what’s given above. Simple yes or no answers just won’t cut it in an interview."  (!)

Comment: No, it will not compile, since it should be `#define X 8`, without `;`

Comment: Sounds very... academic... :)

Comment: Well, it's also an error (in C89, and under any sane warnings set and programmer guidelines) to not `return 0;` or some other number at the end of `main`...

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs - It'll compile, it'll just produce double semicolons (i.e. an empty statement after the `++8` statement).

Comment: Poor interview question.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Correct, thanks. I was not aware that my compiler will eat extra semicolons.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs - If it complains about that under your warnings settings, you probably shouldn't fix it, but it is technically valid.

Comment: @ Everyone : the semi-colon was a mistake, but the code will not compile because ++8 is invalid...  my question is why?  Is it my explanation, theirs, both, or neither?

Comment: I think it's a poor explanation. A macro _might_ expand to an expression that is an lvalue so it's not the fact that `X` is a macro that means it doesn't refer to "a place in memory", it's what it is defined as that matters. E.g. `#define X var` // `int main() { int var = 5; ++X; }` would be fine.

Comment: @Torp: sure, it does sound academic, the purpose of interview questions like this is to see whether you know C's formal definition. If you know it doesn't compile but can't express why, then you have an informal understanding of C that might be quite strong, but such a person probably isn't in a position to (for example) write a compiler or represent the company at C1x standards meetings. That said, this is a *very* early filter question for removing people not suitable for such high-faluting tasks. More likely it's intended as a proxy for C expertise, and will generate false negatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this explanation as bunk as I think it is?

Yes.

> "Strictly speaking, the operand of the prefix (or postfix) increment operator must be a non-modifiable lvalue...

What? A non-modifiable lvalue is something like `const int n;` - you can take its address (via `&`) but you can't assign to it (via `=`, `+=`, or `++`). You can't increment something that's not modifiable.

To quote the standard (6.5.3.1 paragraph 1):

> The operand of the preﬁx increment or decrement operator shall have qualiﬁed or 
>   unqualiﬁed real or pointer type and shall be a modiﬁable lvalue.

Ahem.

> X is a macro, which means that it does not identify a place in memory – macros use simple text replacement via the preprocessor.

This is bogus. Macros don't exist in the C language*. They're part of the preprocessor, which has no concept of lvalues, rvalues, expressions, or memory. *This particular macro* expands to an integer constant, *which is an rvalue*, but macros themselves have nothing to do with any of the above. See [Steve Jessop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075565/is-this-explanation-accurate-for-c-code-that-wont-compile/7075721#7075721) for a counterexample of a macro being an lvalue.

The correct answer is that the statement expands to `++8`, and since `8` is an rvalue it cannot be used as an argument to `++` (in either form), and so it will not compile. Also, depending on whether you intend this code to be compiled as C89 or C99, leaving `main` without an explicit `return` value probably gives undefined behavior.

* If this is going to be the accepted answer, I suppose I ought to clarify this bit: the preprocessor *is* a part of the C programming language. It is specified in the C standard, and a compiler has to implement preprocessing in order to be a C compiler. However, the C "language" (i.e. the syntax, semantics, library, etc.) doesn't interact with the preprocessor - once you get to the stage where you start dealing with lvalues and rvalues, the preprocessor has long since been done and all macros are fully expanded. The *macros themselves* don't have any place in the syntax, since they aren't part of the "language." There was some debate (in Steve Jessop's answer) about whether the use of the term "language" here is misleading, and I agree with him that it is, I just can't find a better word to use instead.

Answer (score 10):

The explanation given is incorrect:

> X is a macro, which means that it does not identify a place in memory
>   – macros use simple text replacement via the preprocessor.

Precisely because macros are just simple text replacement, they *can* expand to an lvalue, or for that matter anything else. For example:

```
int x;
#define X x

int main() {
    ++X;
}
```

is OK. It's true that the macro itself doesn't have a place in memory, but that's irrelevant to whether `++X;` is well-formed, since `++X;` doesn't mean, "increment the macro X", it means "expand the macro X and then stick `++` on the front, `;` on the back, and perform syntactic and semantic analysis on the result".

What the explanation says about "macros", it should say about *integer constants*. `8` is not an lvalue, and that's what matters here.

With that change, the explanation is OK [Edit - as Chris points out in a comment, it's still not OK, it writes "the operand of the prefix (or postfix) increment operator must be a **non-modifiable** lvalue": that should read "modifiable"]

Comment: +1 macros are not part of the C language itself and are totally unrelated to lvalues, rvalues, expressions and memory. It is only the expansion of the macro that is relevant. (Though saying the argument of `++` must be a non-modifiable lvalue is also false.)

Comment: I'm not sure it's helpful to say that macros are not part of "the C language itself". They aren't optional, they're part of the standard. But if you want to chop the standard up into "language" vs "libraries" vs "preprocessor", such that for example `sizeof` is "part of the language" whereas `INT_MIN` is "not part of the language", then you can certainly make a clean division between the preprocessor, "compiler proper", standard headers, linker, and possibly some other components, since the stages of translation are clearly separated in the standard.

Comment: And, heh, I missed that typo "non-modifiable".

Comment: I think that division is helpful. `#define ever (;;)` doesn't produce anything that's meaningful syntax unless you use it as `for ever { ... }`, but _only_ a macro could do something like that because of the fact that the preprocessor happens without any syntax parsing.

Comment: @Chris: I agree the division is helpful, what I'm cautious of is calling the division "the C language" vs "things that I'm going to say are not part of the language, despite them being part of an international standard titled, "Programming languages -- C". We could be picky, and say, "aha, but that standard has a chapter called "Language", but if we did we'd lose the useful distinction, because preprocessing is part of that chapter ;-). So the division is useful, the terminology is slightly tricky. Not a problem with people who know C, it's beginners who suffer from misleading names.

Comment: I didn't mean that the preprocessor isn't part of the language, just that it's not part of the language's syntax. I could say "syntax" but the syntax is a smaller part of the language as a whole. `memcpy(0, 0, 5);` isn't a _syntax_ error.

Answer (score 2):

It won't compile for the exact same reason that :

```
8 = 8+1;
```

won't compile.

You cannot modify (here increment) a constant.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is only correct about that the code will not compile, but it is very wrong in all other aspects.

It completely misses the fact that compiler will not see `X`, it will see `++8;;`, so the whole rant about whether an operator could be applied to `X` makes no sense. It would be so much better to answer just “No” than giving such an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile, since location values are required for the prefix operator. 8 being a constant, it fails. You can read further about L-value here : [L-Value and R-Value Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)